# How can I paste a defvar into the minibuffer?

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, query-replace, markdown

I've written a regular expression to transform Markdown links into Org Mode links and I've stored it into a variable.

```
(defvar markdown-link-to-org-regexp "s/\[\(.+\)\](\(.+\))/[[\2][\1]]")
```

I'm using Doom and Evil mode so next time I type `:` so I go to the minibuffer I'd like to bring that string into the minibuffer. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Copy the region and then yank it (`C-y`) into the minibuffer?

Comment: The region as plain text won't be available when I need it. That regex will live in `init.el` and the usage will happen when editing some org file and pasting some content from the internet. So the request is to bring to the minibuffer a predefined string from a variable.

Comment: Note that you need to quote all the backslashes. Maybe, that is the actual problem. The right expression would be: `(defvar markdown-link-to-org-regexp "s/\\[\\(.+\\)\\](\\(.+\\))/[[\\2][\\1]]")`.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interactive function (aka command), which `insert`s this string. Then put this function on a key binding.

```
(defun my-insert-regex ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format "%S" markdown-link-to-org-regexp)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c i") #'my-insert-regex)
```

When doing `M-:` you then just have to press `C-c i` to insert this string at the prompt.

Note, that your regex is eventualy wrong and needs more escape characters. `re-builder` can help you construct this regex.

---

Second option:

This `M-:` promt normaly supports a history. You just need to type or paste it once, then you can retrieve former inputs with `<up>` and `<down>` keys. `C-r` searches backwards in the history. (`C-r` maybe has a different keybinding in Doom, Evil).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your use case. You can copy text and paste (yank) text into the minibuffer, as @NickD pointed out in a comment. If the text isn't in the kill ring, but is actually stored in a file, then you don't need to invoke the minibuffer to run it. You can wrap it in a function and run it directly:

```
(defun my-regex-set ()
  (interactive)
  (defvar markdown-link-to-org-regexp "s/\[\(.+\)\](\(.+\))/[[\2][\1]]"))
```

With this function defined, you can call it with `M-x my-regex-set`, or you can bind it to a key combo.